# How to change title for the tab of User Add Page of Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django and wanted to change the default title for the tab of User Add Page of Django admin as marked in the pic :

[image]

and my admin.py file is :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So what should be done to change it??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you have to add following function to your admin file :

```
    def add_view(self,request, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        extra_context = {'title': 'Type here new title for the User Add Page tab'}

        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).add_view(request,form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

Your admin.py file will look like this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
    def add_view(self,request, form_url='', extra_context=None):

        extra_context = {'title': 'Type here new title for the User Add Page tab'}

        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).add_view(request,form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

That's it.